# How to load images and spritesheets with Phaser 3 and Webpack correctly?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, phaser-framework

I have a Vue app with Webpack and Phaser 3 and I am trying to load images and spritesheets in my main scene.

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor () {
    super({
      key: 'MainScene'
    })
  };

  preload () {
    this.load.image('sand', require('@/assets/sand.png'))
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', require('@/assets/dude.png'), { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 })
  };

  create () {
   this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'sand').setOrigin(0, 0)

   let player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude')
   player.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
  }

  update () {
   // update
  }
}
```

This works fine for the sand image, but not for the spritesheet dude.png, which I downloaded from the Phaser tutorial [here](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part1). My browser console output is

```
Local data URIs are not supported: dude
```

After researching, I found [this tutorial](https://supernapie.com/blog/loading-assets-as-data-uri-in-phaser-3/) to use data URIs in Phaser. After using that technique the spritesheet is loaded, but what I found out is that Webpack requires both images differently and I cannot figure out why. Also it is not recommended to use lots of data URIs when deploying the app to a server.

require('@/assets/sand.png') resolves to `"/static/img/sand.79c51a8.png"`

require('@/assets/dude.png') resolves to a base64 string.

My Webpack conf seems to have the correct loader

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
   limit: 10000,
   name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

[EDIT]:
Keeri's comment helped me find out that the sand image is bigger than the dude image, and even way bigger than the limit set for the url-loader in the Webpack config. So I set the limit to 1 to always fall back to the file-loader, which seems to work fine for every image.

It feels a bit hacked to define the url-loader and then skip it, but from what I've read, Phaser doesn't want images base64 anyway. So maybe the best way is to remove the url-loader from my Webpack config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limit: 10000` [sets the maximum size of a file in bytes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader#limit), if your image exceeds that size, then the default `file-loader` (file path) is used rather than `url-loader` (base64)

Comment: Setting the limit to false or removing it (to set no limit at all) kept me from importing the sand image, which worked fine before. But this hint helped me find out that the sand image is bigger than the dude image, and even way bigger than the limit. So I set the limit to 1 to always fall back to the file-loader, which seems to work fine for every image.

It feels a bit hacked to define the url-loader and then skip it, but from what I've read, Phaser doesn't want base64 anyway. So maybe the best way is to remove the url-loader from my Webpack config.

Comment: if you wish to have assets downloadable via separate GET requests (recommended over base64), then yes use file-loader rather than url-loader

Comment: glad that helped ^^ feel free to mark this as the "accepted" answer if your question has been resolved